# Разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

"Пришел я встретить вас." Каким членом предложения является неопределенная форма глагола? Я думаю, что глагол выражен подлежащим. Но есть сомнения.
Я учусь в колледже, у нас не преподают русский язык. Это не домашнее задание!

Answer (score 1):

Глагол не может быть выражен подлежащим. У вас полная путаница в терминологии. А вопрос ваш уж очень смахивает на домашнее задание (уже в который раз!).

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее: подлежащее выражено глаголом. Но в данном случае инфинитив выполняет либо роль сказуемого в безличном предложении, либо - обстоятельства цели в неполном предложении.

Comment: Не может быть "либо-либо". Налицо простое распространенное предложение. Просто на этом форуме есть правило насчет домашних заданий. Такие вопросы не допускаются.

Comment: Ставьте вопрос от сказуемого: пришел зачем? с какой целью? - встретить. Слово 'встретить' обозначает цель. Какой второстепенный член предложения указывает на цель? Обстоятельство, как было сказано в ответе Элен.